# Parameter increments after every iteration when using macro

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

So i have this macro (basically a for loop):

```
(defmacro for ((parameter start-value end-value &optional (step 1)) &body e)
  (let ((func-name (gensym))
        (end (gensym)))
    `(labels ((,func-name (,parameter ,end)
                  (if (<= ,parameter ,end) 
                      (progn ,@e 
                             (,func-name (+ ,parameter ,step) ,end)))))
       (,func-name ,start-value ,end-value))))
```

And i want to test it with this:

```
(print (let ((j 0) (k 1))
      (for (i 1 10 (incf k)) (print i))))
```

What i get now is:

```
1, 3, 6, 10, NIL.
```

which means that my step increments after each iteration, but i want it to increment only once in the beginning for this output:

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, NIL.
```

What's wrong with my macro and what should i do?

Comment: Just in case, this is a simple and extensible `for` loop: https://github.com/Shinmera/for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compute the step value outside the loop:

```
CL-USER 12 > (defmacro for ((parameter start-value end-value
                             &optional (step 1))
                            &body e)
               (let ((func-name (gensym))
                     (step-name (gensym))
                     (end (gensym)))
                 `(labels ((,func-name (,parameter ,end ,step-name)
                             (when (<= ,parameter ,end) 
                               ,@e 
                               (,func-name (+ ,parameter ,step-name)
                                           ,end
                                           ,step-name))))
                    (,func-name ,start-value ,end-value ,step))))
FOR

CL-USER 13 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(for (i 1 10 (incf k)) (print i))))

(LABELS ((#:G954 (I #:G956 #:G955)
           (WHEN (<= I #:G956) (PRINT I) (#:G954 (+ I #:G955) #:G956 #:G955))))
  (#:G954 1 10 (INCF K)))

CL-USER 14 > (let ((j 0) (k 1))
               (for (i 1 10 (incf k))
                 (print i)))

1 
3 
5 
7 
9 
NIL
```

If you don't want to pass the step-value all the time, you need an outer `LET` binding its value.

Note: some Lisp implementations (many interpreters and some compilers) don't support TCO (tail call optimisation).

Comment: but what if i need the result of my macro to be the value of the last expression in the body? because the result now is always nil.

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: best ask a new question.

Comment: you don't mind if i use your code in my new question?

Comment: @AntonKaravaev: no problem